# Creating some flakiness inside a Belgian Liege waffle

Tags: baking, dough, pastry, waffle

I have a pretty good basic recipe for Belgian Liege waffles. Its as follows: 1 egg, 40g butter, 5g salt, 20g sugar, 250g flour, 6g dry yeast, 90ml milk, once the ingredients are combined and the dough doubles in size, add pearl sugar and divide into waffle sized balls and let rest 45min before pressing in waffle iron.

This recipe is pretty good, however from my recent trip to Belgium and the various waffles I ate, one stood out more than the rest where the inside of the waffle was slightly more yellow and the dough was more like flakey/stringy bread on the inside (like challah bread / croissant hybrid). Any idea how I can adjust my recipe to achieve a result that is more like this?

I am thinking along the lines of changing the butter ratio and perhaps adding some egg yolks, but not sure if this will accomplish this.

Also, would substituting milk for water help with this?  and lastly, swapping the 20g sugar for honey?

I appreciate any advice.

Comment: Are you melting the butter? You could try using cold butter and doing the same thing as when making pie-dough. Croissants are a hybrid between phillo dough and yeast dough; so this might have the desired result.